# Java + SOAP: Unexpected IndexOutOfBoundsException when executing the same SOAP service twice

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jakarta-ee, soap

I'm using the Jakarta SOAP API (jakarta.xml.soap) Maven library in conjunction with Java. I'm attempting to execute the same SOAP service (let's call this service A) twice in a row to retrieve a session ID of some sort. I'm using a Mac.

I'm able to do this operation twice in a row in SOAP UI 5.5.0, but am unable to reproduce the same result in Java 12:

```
responseMessage = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance().createConnection().call(
MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage(new MimeHeaders(), someSoapByteStream), targetURL);
```

This is the SOAP body I provide:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:user="redacted">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
    <user:getSessionId>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <userCode>?</userCode>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <ipAddress>?</ipAddress>
    </user:getSessionId>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I am calling a POST URL ON some URL `https:{redacted}`, and getting this back on the first service call:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
    <ns2:getSessionIdResponse xmlns:ns2="redacted">
        <sessionId>1caf23db-a04c-11ea-8511-e1c09ad12ebb</sessionId>
    </ns2:getSessionIdResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

When I attempt to execute this service A twice in a row in SOAP using Java, the first call is successful but the second one returns the following Exception:

```
    Caused by: com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: 
    com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Message send failed
    at 
    com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:127)
    at utils.plugins.LocalSOAPUtils.callMessage(LocalSOAPUtils.java:115)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Message send failed
    at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(HttpSOAPConnection.java:259)
    at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:123)
    ... 4 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Range [0, 0 + -1) out of bounds for length 1024
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckFromIndexSize(Preconditions.java:82)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkFromIndexSize(Preconditions.java:343)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkFromIndexSize(Objects.java:424)
    at java.base/java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:155)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.PosterOutputStream.write(PosterOutputStream.java:78)
    at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.writeTo(MessageImpl.java:1396)
    at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(HttpSOAPConnection.java:216)
... 5
```

The only way I can get this service to execute successfully again is to run the code from the very beginning, in which case the first call will succeed again but the second will not.

What could possibly be going on here to cause this behaviour? Are there some static variables being set within Jakarta SOAP that is causing the first call to always succeed but the second to always fail? What exactly about the second service call is out of bounds?

Comment: Is it possible your someSoapByteStream is null or something else is wrong with it? Could you maybe share your implementation?

Comment: Hi @Taschi, it turns out that someSoapByteStream did have something wrong with it; namely, its position had moved the second time I called it. I've answered my question accordingly below.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so it turns out I was calling the above method on the same byte stream, which meant that the second time I called it, the position of the stream had moved, therefore causing the above error.

I fixed the issue by simply initializing a new ByteStream:

`responseMessage = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance().createConnection().call(
MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage(new MimeHeaders(), new ByteArrayInputStream(someSoapByteStreamAsString.getBytes())), targetURL);`